# sun grid engine can't get host information for exec node

Tags: linux, centos, sungridengine

I'm setting up a gridengine on Centos 6 for a small cluster of two nodes (A and B). I ran inst_sge -x -m on both and added B as exec node to A. then when I try to run qhost, I got,

```
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global                  -               -     -       -       -       -       -
A                       lx26-amd64      8  0.15   23.5G  498.6M    9.8G     0.0
B                       -               -     -       -       -       -       -
```

node B doesn't return any information. when I ran qhost on B, similar output is returned with A/B switched. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a side effect of installing two hosts as masters(`inst_sge -m -x`).  You should install one as master and the other as a shadow-master(`inst_sge -sm -x`) or just an execution host (`inst_sge -x`).